# <script> in $.html() $.load() what is the spec?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

jQuery does not seem to document how it behaves when using $.html() or $.load() to insert an HTML document fragment into the current DOM:

**What does it do with `< script >` tags?**

They are executed, though. But are nowhere to be found in the DOM. It seems jQuery inserts the script blocks just for a moment into the DOM or evals it.

There is no documentation this regard. Do you know any way to tune it, i.e. disable it?
This has implications of security in nature!

Comment: Can you post what code you're using?

Answer (score 4):

The `<script>` tags are stripped out of the code and explicitly executed after the DOM has been updated.

If you use "$.load()" with a URL that's got a selector in it (it's a hack-y feature of the API), like this:

```
$.load("http://something #stuff", ... )
```

then it will **not** run the scripts.

Comment: I see this behavior. But is there any documentation this regard? Is there an "official" switch?

Comment: None that I know of, which is why [I logged a bug about it](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6307).

Comment: A consequence of this behavior is that if you have `<script>`-s that use `document.write` and you insert such a HTML with jQuery, it will suddenly replace the whole page with the output of `document.write`-s. That's because the script is executed when the whole document was already finished. If you insert pages into other pages with AJAX, this can cause some nasty surprises... things that work fine when visited directly, will destroy the page when inserted with AJAX.